# Javascript creating some weird "cache"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I searched for some solution and I couldn't find anything.

I have a project using the CodeIgniter and is basically AJAX-based (because I can't refresh the page). My view and my JS are on different files and every time I load a view, I load your respective JS file.

When I load a JavaScript file and then I call another page (and, consequently, a new JavaScript), even though I remove the JavaScript of the previous page from header, their functions keep alive, causing some times double calls or weird calls.

I.E.:

I have a register page with an `<ul id=tabs>` and an artist page with an another `<ul id=tabs>` (they are distinct pages).

On JavaScript to register, I have the following function:

```
$(document).on("click", "#tabs li", function() {
    album.change($(this));
    if ($("#tabs").find('li').length < 7 && $(this).is(':last-child')) album.create();
});
```

And, on JavaScript to artist page, I have this function:

```
$("#tabs li a").on("click", function(e) {
    var target = base_url+hash[1];

    tab = $(this).data("tab");

    $("#tabs li").removeClass('active');
    $("."+tab).parent().addClass("active");

    $(".tab").hide();
    $("#"+tab).fadeIn(100);

    if (tab == "bio-tab") {
        slider.photo();
        target = target+"/bio";
    }

    ($(document).find(".artist.intro").length > 0) ? $(document).scrollTop("520") :       $(document).scrollTop("90");

    History.pushState(null, null, target);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

When I click on a li of `<ul id=tabs>` on artist page, it executes both functions.

It looks like AJAX is creating something like a cache of my JS files, or something like this. There is a way to destroy the file after I change the page?

JIT, set the ajaxcache to false is not an alternative because all my AJAX requests are by post.

Comment: use class in your `body` tag to namespace your selector, ie `.register` for register page, `.artist` for artist page, and always use it on your selectors

Comment: Hey Jonathan, thanks for the reply. The issue is a little bigger than this, what I use here was only an example. I have another things that can't be solving using this solution. ie, I load a modal and your js. If I load it again, my controller calls again their js and when I use a function of the modal, it doubles the function.

Comment: It's not ajax that creates a "cache". It seems you're loading the second function via AJAX (bad idea) and you're starting to stack events (bind them multiple times). That's why it's a BAD idea to load HTML with JS via ajax and it shouldn't be done. We can't do much more without seeing more code and HTML (especially that ajax request you do and the method you determined that both functions are invoked).

Comment: Tks, N.B. The deal is, all my project is based on ajax, because is an streaming project and I can't refresh the page (to keep the player running). In other words, every single call of my project is an ajax request, that loads a view and, inside this view, the javascript file.
My question (and also a plea for help) is: even though I remove the html and their javascript code, their functions will keep alive? (cuz it is what is happening).

Comment: Yes, I realized that you're loading the javascript on every ajax request but that's SO BAD. Why would you do that? Why don't you load only the data you need and construct your JS when your site loads? That's how S.P.A.s are done. What you're doing is losing control over what binds where and when, you stacked events.

Comment: When I start, the project already works this way :/ This can be a solution for a new version of or tool but, for now, as I can see, I'll have to ever find an workaround. But, anyway, tks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$("#tabs li").on("click", function() {` instead of `$(document).on("click", "#tabs li", function() {`.

When passing a second parameter to the `.on` function which is an element list, jQuery registers a live event (the same as the `.live()` function in earlier versions of jQuery), which means the event will be attached to any dynamic loaded content as well

Comment: Hey Pierre, tks. Sometimes this is a good idea like an workaround but some stuffs on system was already in use when I arrived, and this is one. But I've made some changes and it works very well now, tks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loading same js libraries again and again. try loading script libraries like this:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```